# How to get an XML element text in a LibreOffice Basic macro?

Tags: xml, macros, libreoffice, openoffice-basic, libreoffice-basic

I have a LibreOffice Basic macros to write/ read XML files. I have ported them from VBA. So far everything seems to be working except for retrieving the text from XML elements. Here is the (simplified) Sub that creates an XML object, writes it to file and reads an XML file  into an XML object:

```
Sub ExportImportXML
Dim oleService, oXMLexp as Object, oXMLimp as Object
Dim oRoot, oNode as Object 
Dim HOME as String

oleService = createUnoService("com.sun.star.bridge.OleObjectFactory")  

' Change this one:
HOME = "C:\tmp"

' Create an XML object to export
oXMLexp = oleService.createInstance("Msxml.DOMDocument")

With oXMLexp
    .async = False 
    .validateOnParse = False 
    .resolveExternals = False 

    oRoot = .createElement("Root") 
    .appendChild(oRoot) 

    oNode = .createElement("ElementA") 
    oNode.Text = "Text of ElementA"                 
    oRoot.appendChild(oNode) 

    MsgBox oNode.xml

    'THIS DOESN'T WORK!
    'MsgBox oNode.Text

    oNode = .createElement("ElementB") 
    oNode.Text = "Text of ElementB"
    oRoot.appendChild(oNode)

    MsgBox .xml

    .Save(HOME & "\test1.xml")
End With

' Create an XML object to import
oXMLimp = oleService.createInstance("Msxml.DOMDocument")

With oXMLimp
    .Load(HOME & "\test1.xml")

    MsgBox .xml

    oNode = .DocumentElement.getElementsByTagName("ElementA").Item(0)
    MsgBox oNode.xml

    'THIS DOESN'T WORK!
    'MsgBox oNode.Text
End With
End Sub
```

As you can see, I can write to a Node using **.Text** but I cannot read from it.

By the way, this works perfectly in VBA.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. For some reason the program doesn't recognize **.Text** property for a Node. It does, however, recognize **.nodeTypedValue**. The difference is that .Text property returns **unformatted** text of this node whereas .nodeTypedValue property returns a **formatted** value of the node.

More details at:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa163921(v=office.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa163921%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

So to make the code above work, substitute **oNode.Text** with **oNode.nodeTypedValue**.

Additional note: if you want to use a specific version of MSXML, you can create an XML object as following (without using OleObjectFactory):

```
oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
```